# WordPress Rest API (python) always response 200 without creating post

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've got a simple Python script which should post to my WordPress Site.

I created Basic Auth with "Application Password" Plugin.

With my test Homepage it's working very fine and the Http Response is 201.

At my real site I always get Response 200 from my Server and nothing happened.
The Plugons are the same, the .htaccess is the same on both sites

```
import requests
import json

url_srcdest = "https://wp-site/?rest_route=/wp/v2/pages/"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
         'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
data = \
    {
        "title":"Testtitle",
        "content":"testcontent",
        "status": "private"
    }

response = requests.post(url_srcdest, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

print(response)
```

`/?rest_route=/` Because I don't want to change permalinks, I'm to affraid, something could happen to the page.
Also with this, the Test-site is working fine.

This is in .htaccess

```
# WPhtc: Begin Custom htaccess
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
# WPhtc: End Custom htaccess

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your host is blocking the creation, you need to contact them and tell them to make an exception in their firewall for your domain so you can post to it